# Instagram Media Insights API - Application does not have permissions

Tags: instagram-api

I've setup a sample FB page and connected an IG account.

I login using the FB Login and retrieve my user and page access tokens, and then I fetch IG Media for that given user. All works fine, but now I'm following the [Insights API Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media/insights) and unfortunately when trying to fetch Insights for a given Media object, I'm getting a HTTP 400 error with the message

```
"(#10) Application does not have permission for this action"
```

I understand that for some advanced features I have to submit for a review, but this is a test-business account that I have setup. I also am querying the Media for my given user only, the one connected to the FB page.

Do I really need to submit for a review just to get insights of a Media, or am I just missing something?